# I get Error parsing JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 when i try to parse a string from a JSON

Tags: node.js, json

```
fs.readFile('./horoscopy.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('File read failed:', err);
      return;
    }
    try {
        const horoscopeJson = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(horoscopeJson.horo.aries.today);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error parsing JSON:', err);
      }
  });
```

This is my code

```
"aries": [
            {
                "yesterday": [
                    "\nСегодня вы вновь обретете несколько ослабшую в последнее время уверенность в себе. Ситуация начнет меняться, причем , как ни странно, в лучшую сторону.\n"
                ],
                "today": [
                    "\nПостарайтесь сегодня не вмешиваться ни в чьи дела. Не разобравшись в тонкостях дела, вы можете натворить чего-то не того, действуя из лучших побуждений.\n"
                ],
                "tomorrow": [
                    "\nНе тратьте сегодня свое и чужое время на всевозможные словесные изыски. Информация должна исходить от вас в четкой и понятной форме, в противном случае возможны малоприятные накладки.\n"
                ],
                "tomorrow02": [
                    "\nПрежде чем покупать то, что вы давно хотели купить, постарайтесь приложить некоторые усилия к тому, чтобы попытаться заплатить не больше, чем эта вещь реально стоит.\n"
                ]
            }
        ],
```

This is the json object I try to parse
Please help, I found similar problems but none of the solutions there helped
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Json parsing is failing because payload is not in correct json format.

Remove "Aries:" and ,(comma) from your payload it should work

```json
    [
        {
             "yesterday": [
                 "\nСегодня вы вновь обретете несколько ослабшую в последнее время уверенность в себе. Ситуация начнет меняться, причем , как ни странно, в лучшую сторону.\n"
             ],
             "today": [
                 "\nПостарайтесь сегодня не вмешиваться ни в чьи дела. Не разобравшись в тонкостях дела, вы можете натворить чего-то не того, действуя из лучших побуждений.\n"
              ],
              "tomorrow": [
                  "\nНе тратьте сегодня свое и чужое время на всевозможные словесные изыски. Информация должна исходить от вас в четкой и понятной форме, в противном случае возможны малоприятные накладки.\n"
              ],
              "tomorrow02": [
                  "\nПрежде чем покупать то, что вы давно хотели купить, постарайтесь приложить некоторые усилия к тому, чтобы попытаться заплатить не больше, чем эта вещь реально стоит.\n"
              ]
        }
    ]
```

Comment: This is not a full json file, i need the aries and the other star signs unfortunately. Maybe I can somehow automatically make this a correct payload, like not manually, cause this file is updated everyday

Answer (score -1):

Try to update a line where you parse with this one:

```
const horoscopeJson = JSON.parse(`{${data}}`);
```

In fact, your file foes not conform to JSON format, that's the problem, curly brackets are missing.